# my power supply died dramatically; is it safe to simply replace it?

Tags: power-supply, hardware-failure, power, desktop-computer

my power supply died last night rather spectacularly: blue sparks, popping sounds, a smell of burning plastic. the computer shut down, then tried to start itself up again, and sparked and popped some more before I was able to turn off the power switch on the back (in retrospect: was that dangerous of me? just reaching toward it to hit its switch?) and unplug it.

so clearly THAT needs to be replaced. but I have to wonder: what are the chances that OTHER components were damaged as well? can I simply buy a new power supply, and expect things to work? or could doing so actually be dangerous? could another component - like the motherboard, graphics card, or hard drives - have been damaged in such a way that plugging in another power supply would simply kill THAT power supply? (or damage other components that somehow survived the first assault?)

I've been building desktops casually, for myself, for a little over 10 years now, but I would by no means consider myself an expert in computer hardware or electronics, and something like this has never happened before. I'm a bit out of my depth.

other details, in case they may be of help:

- the power supply is a Cooler Master RS-460-PSAR-I3. I bought it about 3 years ago, when I built this computer. (no internal components were reused, except two SATA drives.)
- I don't overclock anything; I never have.
- one of the two case's side fans died a few months ago. these fans are an unusual size (250mm), so had trouble finding a replacement, and then never got around to replacing it. I can't deny the possibility that things have been running hot for a while. (I was worried about this when the fan first broke, so kept an eye on a CPU temp program for a couple days afterwards. I don't remember the numbers, but I remember being unconcerned, though I am aware that these programs are unreliable by their nature.)

thanks for any help!

Comment: We can't know for sure as there's a lot of other factors involved. One of the easiest ways to tell if a piece is broken without powering it is to look for physical damage - browning, chipped pieces, etc.

Comment: We would only be able to speculate.  The first step you replace the power supply, only at that point, can you determine if anything else should be replaced.

Comment: sure. if some other component WAS broken, is it possible that plugging it into power might just break other things? I understand it may be hard to know, but does that seem like a real risk, or just paranoia on the part of a noob? :P

*edit* oh, thanks for that link, techie0007

Comment: yeah, after reading over the link techie supplied, I think MY question is close enough to count as a duplicate. thanks, everyone :)

Answer (score -1):

You may have damaged other components. Before you try anything else, I would suggest removing the hard drive from the computer and then trying a new power supply. That way, at the very least, you don't lose any data if the hard drive happened to still be okay.

Comment: the hard drives definitely are the most important. are hard drives known to be particularly sensitive or resilient vs power surges? (there are three SATA drives in there.)

Comment: How is my answer down voted?

Comment: @mavx717x - This easily could have been a comment, which after receiving information some additional information, leading to a more specific and detailed answer.